# How can I use a member function pointer in libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, function-pointers, libcurl, pointer-to-member

I am using libcurl I have my downloading of files inside of a class, to which I want to see a progress function. I notice I can set a typical function pointer by

```
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func3);
```

However, I would like to set it to a function pointer to my class. I can get the code to compile with

```
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, &MyClass::progress_func3);
```

and the `progress_func3` function will get called. The problem is, as soon as it returns there will be a "Buffer overrun detected!" error through, saying the program can not safely continue and execute, and must be terminated. (It is a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error window, I am using Visual Studio 2010).

When I use a function, there is no problem, but when I use a member function pointer, I will get this error. How can I use a member function pointer in libcurl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-static member function needs a `this` pointer to be callable. You can't provide that `this` pointer with this type of interface, so using a non-static member function is not possible.

You should create a "plain C" function as your callback, and have that function call the member function on the appropriate `MyClass` instance.

Try something like:

```
int my_progress_func(void *clientp, ...)
{
   MyClass *mc = static_cast<MyClass*>(clientp);
   mc->your_function(...);
   return 0; // or something else
}
```

Then:

```
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA,     &your_myclass_object);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, my_progress_func);
```

(You're responsible for the type match here, obviously. If you attach anything else but a `MyClass` pointer to the progress data, you're on your own.)

Comment: How can I end up calling my class? The progress function has predetermined parameters that automatically get sent

Comment: I must have just hit refresh on the page at the wrong time. That worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Works perfect. When calling `curl_easy_opt()` inside the class then use `this` instead of `&your_myclass_object`. May sound trivial for C++ pros but for me as a beginner it was a challenge of few minutes to sort this out.

Comment: @Mat: why do you use `static_cast`? `my_progress_func(MyClass * clientp, ...)` and then `clientp->your_function(...)` does the same and I do not really see **in this constellation** any advantage of `static_cast`

Comment: @AlBundy: because the progress callback is declared as taking a `void*`, not a `YourType*`. It's probably ok here, but I'll let you look at the standard to figure out in which case the function types are compatible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can this using boost::bind(). For example:

```
boost::bind(&MyClass::progress_func3, this);
```

is a pointer to a method that returns void and has no arguments. If your callback needs arguments, use placeholders as follows:

```
boost::bind(&MyClass::progress_func3, this, _1, _2)
```

The `this` pointer can be replaced with a point to an instance of `MyClass`.

EDIT:
You should be able to use boost::function<> and function ptr types relatively interchangeable. For example:

```
typedef boost::function< void (int, short) > Callback;
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef void (Callback)(int);
```

You may have to layer it with a function in between to make the compiler happy. I know that I've defined a callback using boost::function<> and passed in a regular function pointer.

Comment: How do you get that to work exactly? I can't seem to find a way to pass a boost::function as the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Class instance 'this' works:

```
static int progressCallback( void * p, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow )
{
    QTWindow * w{ static_cast< QTWindow * >( p ) };
    emit w->uploadProgressData( ulnow, ultotal );
    return 0;
}

curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progressCallback );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, this );
```